# How to make html textbox lowercase by default

Tags: javascript, html

I have this login form:

```
<div id="loginform">
    <div>
        <img id="loginLogo" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="UserNameBox" type="text" id="tbEmail" style="outline-style:none;"
        tabindex="1" runat="server" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) validateExample()"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="PasswordBox" type="password" id="tbPassword"
        tabindex="2" style="outline-style:none" runat="server" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) validateExample()"
        />
    </div>
    <div id="validationError" class="validationError" runat="server"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 15px;" tabindex="3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cbRememberMe" name="rememberMe" runat="server"
        tabindex="4" />remember me</div>
    <center>
        <input type="button" class="rounded-corners" onclick="validateExample()"
        value="Login" tabindex="5" />
    </center>
</div>
```

in my device the first letter's default case of the username textbox is in Uppercase. How can i make it in lowercase by default but the user can still make it in Uppercase in case his username starts with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Normally that's specific to the phone and OS. My phone used to do that, always starting with uppercase when you first select the box. The new OS I installed on my phone doesn't do that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do a lower case transformation during validation rather than during typing. You can use [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) when you validate it.

If you insist doing a live transformation, turn <kbd>CAPSLOCK ON</kbd> and [here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/JAyt2/):

```
document.getElementById('tbEmail').onkeyup = function() {
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
}​
```

Also, You would not want to prevent the user from using capital letters. The user might think there's something wrong (normally users think there's something wrong when something doesn't act normally)